# TabView tabItem image move to top

Tags: swiftui, tabview, tabitem

I learned how to create a tabBar like UIKit tabBar in swiftUI. And I want to move the center tabItem to top . Is there any way I can achieve this?

TabView code

```
TabView {
        ViewTasks()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "list.bullet.below.rectangle")
                Text("View Tasks")
        }
        AddTask()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle").font(.system(size: 60))
        }
        CategoriesTasks()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "square.grid.2x2")
                Text("Categories")
        }
    }
```

Visual Example
 [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First idea is to use `ZStack` so you can cover `tabItem` with your own tappable image. Here is example:

```swift
struct TabViewModel: View {

    @State var showActionSheet: Bool = false

    var body: some View {


        ZStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                TabView {

                            Text("list")
                                .tabItem {
                                    Image(systemName: "list.bullet.below.rectangle")
                            }

                            Text("plus")
                                .tabItem {
                                    Text(" ")
                            }

                            Text("categories")
                                .tabItem {
                                    Image(systemName: "square.grid.2x2")
                            }
                        }

                Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 2, x: 0, y: 5)
                    .offset(x: geometry.size.width / 2 - 20, y: geometry.size.height - 80)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.showActionSheet.toggle()
                }
            }

        }
        .actionSheet(isPresented: $showActionSheet) {
            ActionSheet(title: Text("some actions"))
        }

    }
}
```

so some image will cover center tabView item, which will be invisible (`Text(" ")`):

[image]
[image]

**update**

if you still need to switch between these 3 views you can use `@State var selection` (don't forget to `tag(...)` tabItems):

```swift
struct TabViewModel: View {

    @State var selection: Int = 0
    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                TabView(selection: self.$selection) {
    //...
                    Text("plus")
                        .tabItem {
                            Text(" ")
                    }.tag(1)
    //...
                .onTapGesture {
                        self.selection = 1
                }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SWIFTUI 2

`.onTapGesture` usage sometimes causes unexpected behavior such as not displaying the overlay view (alert, sheets or fullscreen) or displaying it when you click another tab. The safer way is to set the selection value with the `.onChange(of:)` method:

```
struct TabViewModel: View {

@State var selection: Int = 0
var body: some View {

    ZStack {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            TabView(selection: self.$selection) {
//...
                Text("plus")
                    .tabItem {
                        Text(" ")
                }.tag(1)
//...
            .onChange(of: selection) { _ in
                self.selection = 1
            }
// ...
```

}