# SwiftUI actionSheet into .tabItem

Tags: swiftui, tabitem, actionsheet

I'm trying to insert a actionSheet into action button into .tabItem. I only see a View with the text "Test 1". Can't make it display a menu with different options?. Thanks in advance.

```
@State var showActionSheet = false
```

...

```
var actionSheet : ActionSheet{

    ActionSheet(title: Text("Crear"), message: Text("Selecciona opción"), buttons: [
        .default(Text("Opción 1")),
        .default(Text("Opción 2")),
        .destructive(Text("Cancel"))
    ])
}
```

...

```
        }.tag(1)

            Text("Test 1")

            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "1.circle")


                    Button(action: {
                        self.showActionSheet.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Display Action Sheet")
                    }
                    .actionSheet(isPresented: $showActionSheet, content: {
                        self.actionSheet  })

                }
```

Comment: This is not possible. TabItem only takes an Image and a Text and it's sole function is to switch views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Apple [says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview):

> Tab views only support tab items of type Text, Image, or an image followed by text. Passing any other type of view results in a visible but empty tab item.

You can use solution, which I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59006711/9982386). Shortly: you make empty tabItem (`Text(" ")`), set `Image` at needed position and use `.onTapGesture`. There I also made example with `ActionSheet`