# Hiding tab bar on a specific page in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, tabview

I am working with a camera in my application. The app allows you to navigate to this camera view with the help of the `TabView` in SwiftUI. However, the problem is, when I am on the camera view, I would like to make the `TabView` hidden. So far I've been trying to find a solution but I cannot seem to find any.

Here is a [screenshot of the code and the view with the tabview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5Cj4.png)

**Note**: The screenshot contains an image if the preview. The camera works fine when I run it on a real device. The problem is that I need the tab bar to be hidden once I've entered the camera view.

And here is an example of the code that I am using:

```
import SwiftUI

struct AppView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView{
            Home()
                .tabItem {
                    // Add icon
                Text("Home")
            }

            MomentsCam()
                .tabItem {
                    // Add icon
                    Text("Camera")
            }.navigationBarHidden(true)

            Moments()
                .tabItem{
                    //Add icon
                     Text("Moments")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than provide a screenshot of the code you will be better off providing the actual code in this question. You'll be downvoted otherwise and I have opted to close this until you do.

Comment: I've added a copy of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59006711/9982386) with TabView for your situation. The same idea: you're using `ZStack` and `@State var selection`. And the idea is to use `.opacity` of `TabView` and `YourCameraView` (which is just `Image(systemName: "plus.circle")` in my example):

```swift
struct TabViewModel: View {

    @State var selection: Int = 0

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                TabView(selection: self.$selection) {

                    Text("list")
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "list.bullet.below.rectangle")
                    }.tag(0)

                    Text("plus")
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "camera")
                    }.tag(1)

                    Text("more categories!")
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "square.grid.2x2")
                    }.tag(2)
                }
                .opacity(self.selection == 1 ? 0.01 : 1)

                Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                    .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 2, x: 0, y: 5)
                    .offset(x: geometry.size.width / 2 - 30, y: geometry.size.height - 80)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.selection = 0
                }
                .opacity(self.selection == 1 ? 1 : 0)
            }

        }

    }
}
```

when you tap on camera tabItem `TabView` becomes invisible

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following code according to your needs.

```
  struct MomentsCam: View {
                var body: some View {
                    Text("Cam")
                }
            }

            struct Moments: View {
                var body: some View {
                    Text("Moments Cam")
                }
            }
            struct AppView: View {

                @State var  showCamera = false
                var body: some View {

                      GeometryReader{ p in
                    ZStack{
                    TabView{
                        Home()
                            .tabItem {
                                // Add icon
                            Text("Home")
                        }

                        Text("holder")
                            .tabItem {
                                // Add icon
                                Text("Camera")
                        }.navigationBarHidden(true).onAppear{
                            self.showCamera = true
                            print(p.size)
                        }

                        Moments()
                            .tabItem{
                                //Add icon
                                 Text("Moments")
                        }
                    }
                        if self.showCamera{
                    MomentsCam().frame(width: p.size.width, height: p.size.height).background(Color.white)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```